# how to use Istio API Key for authorisation to a service?

Tags: kubernetes, api-key, istio, kubernetes-security

I found the following documentation on istio on how to create an API Key

https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/apikey/

But i am unable to find any documentation or examples on how to use the thing to secure a service.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Istio represents [*Mixer*](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#mixer) configuration [Model](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/mixer-overview/) in terms of propagating authorization policies within the service mesh. Policy and telemetry features are actually based on configuring such kind of *[CRD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/)* resources as:

[*Handlers*](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/mixer-overview/#handlers) - define appropriate [*Adapters*](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/adapters/) and a communication way between Mixer and some external infrastructure software;

[*Instances*](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/mixer-overview/#instances) - introduce the source data set across particular [attributes](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/attribute-vocabulary/) being afforded with related Adapter.

[*Rules*](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/mixer-overview/#rules) - bind specific *Handler* to *Instance*, matching rule expressions.

You may also find predefined [templates](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/) for individual adapters, the [link](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/apikey/) mentioned above in the origin question reflects the particular template for generic [API key](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/), but it doesn't describe any process for authorization policy enforcement.

In context, to leverage using authentication requests with API keys, you will probably require to implement [*Analytics*](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/analytics/) or [*Authorization*](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/authorization/) templates, using i.e. [Apigee](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/adapters/apigee/) adapter. You can visit [Apigee's Istio Mixer Adapter](https://github.com/apigee/istio-mixer-adapter) repository with a quite good tutorial securing mesh service authentication within API key [header](https://github.com/apigee/istio-mixer-adapter#authentication-with-api-key).